# incognito livecd (gentoo based) won't recognize my hard drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, privacy, livecd, gentoo

How do i mount my hd? I looked into /etc/fstab and there's only firmware and portage there so i guess mounting won't work, i need to add my hd to fstab first?

Answer (score 0):

Your hard disk does not have to be listed in `fstab` to be mounted. I'd first list the detected hard disks using `fdisk -l` and then try to mount them using

```
mount /dev/<hard-disk-id> /mount/point
```

Both require root privileges so switch over to root using `su root` and then issue those commands